# create one event Handler for more than one button in Mobile Flex programming

Tags: java, apache-flex, flex-mobile

I created a screen(calculator) with bunch of buttons,i can handle button event with one handler.But i want to know that can we do a one handler for all buttons......
like
in java 
we can perform the task of perticular button by like this

```
if(event.source=="button1")
{

}
else if(event.source=="button2")
{

}
```

so,can we do the same thing in mobile Flex programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event.currentTarget .

```
<s:Button id="btn_one" width="100" height="30" label="One" 
click="onClick_btn_one(event)"/>


private function onClick_btn_one(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(event.currentTarget.id ==  "btn_one")
    {
         trace("button one")
    }

 }
```

Comment: @agreed an +1ed, also if using this concept switch statements work out well.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the object, which dispatched event by `event.target`, and then check property you need (e.g. `Button(event.target).label` or `Button(event.target).id`).